# Remove extra braces

Tags: smartparens, balanced-parentheses

I have some text like this

```
This is a {{text}} with { { {some {extra} unneeded {
{and ugly}} braces 
}}}.
```

Is there a way to remove the extra unneeded parenthesis so that the result is

```
This is a {text} with {some {extra} unneeded 
{and ugly} braces 
}.
```

Or something like this, up to whitespace. I use `smartparens` but I couldn't find anything there to resolve this (other than going through each extra pair and removing it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `sp-unwrap-sexp`.

In your example, having

- `sp-unwrap-sexp` bind to `M-Backspace`
- `sp-next-sexp` bind to `C-M-n`
- `sp-down-sexp` bind to `C-M-d`

and a cursor in the beginning of the text, I do:

1. `C-M-d` to go to `{text}`
2. `M-Backspace` to remove outer `{}`
3. `C-M-n` 3 times to go to `{ { {some {extra} unneeded {`
4. `M-Backspace` 2 times to get `{some {extra} unneeded {` of course matching braces `}` were also removed
5. `C-M-d` `C-M-n` `C-M-n` `C-M-n` to go to the last `{` on the first line
6. `M-Backspace` and we are done.

PS

Here is short demo: https://youtu.be/LJMPnIUXTW0

Comment: Thanks. Although, I was hoping for something that I can run on a buffer to automatically do this. In general, I find Emacs' handling of paired delimiters quite limited.

Comment: Well, that was not clear from the Q desc. To do it automatically you have to actually create an interactive function that does it for you. Or try to come up with the keyboard macro.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `sp-raise-sexp`.

From the documentation (<kbd>C-h f sp-raise-sexp</kbd>):

> Unwrap the current list and kill everything inside except next
>   expression.

For example, with this:

```
{{text}}
```

You can:

- place point/cursor on the second `{`
- <kbd>M-x sp-raise-sexp</kbd>

And you will get:

```
{text}
```

Comment: Or the builtin `raise-sexp`, no need to used smartparens for this.